# Be Able To Post Only YouTube Videos Under 2 Minutes

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, youtube

Is there any way for a website to let users embed ONLY short youtube videos. Let's say 2min or shorter.

So when they try to embed the youtube video and if it's over 2 minutes they get an error that tells them "Your video is too long, please choose another" etc...

Is this possible?

Just to be clear, I'm not looking to edit the youtube video length, just prohibit users from posting of videos that are too long.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you may be able to use the youtube api to get the video length- but im just guessing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's to help you get started:

The base api URL is `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID?v=2&alt=json`.

```
<?php

$video_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/a_kAUiJwRs0?v=2&alt=json"),true);

echo $video_data['entry']['title']['$t']." is ".$video_data['entry']['media$group']['yt$duration']['seconds']." seconds long.";
```

Output:

`Love, Fate, Love - Final Approach ED Single Love, Fate, Love Original Soundtrack is 283 seconds long.`

Replace `a_kAUiJwRs0` with your video ID. You may `print_r` on `$video_data` to see all the values you get.

Once you have their video ID, you may check if their duration (in seconds) is longer or shorter than 120 seconds, and reject or accept based on that.

I would recommending reading [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Understanding_Video_Entries) to see what video responses will have. (You can always `var_dump` to see exactly what it returns)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the XML data from:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoId}
```

which includes the duration.   Just check if that is over 120 seconds long

Comment: Hi - thank you - is this data available for all video. I have no youtube api experience. Thanks

Comment: If you see my answer, you have all the data from the response. It can be accessed through `entry->media$group`, you may want to use JSON and use an associative array.